# JS How to extract data from a promise

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, async-await

I am struggling to extract data from an API call. I need it to return an array of keys but I keep getting `[object Promise]` when I try to render.

```
const apiKey = '*****';
const container = document.getElementById('root');

const Yelp = {
  async search(term, location, searchBy) {
    let response = await fetch(`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search?term=${term}&location=${location}&sort_by=${searchBy}`, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${apiKey}`
      }
    })

    if (response.ok) {
      let jsonResponse = await response.json()
      return jsonResponse.businesses.map(business => {
        return business
      })

    }
  }
}

console.log(Yelp.search('pasta', 'london', 'best_match'));
```

Comment: `Yelp.search` is `async` therefore returns a Promise .. you can await that promise (if you do so in a `async` function) or use the `.then` method of the promise to access the resolved value of the promise

Comment: Yelp.search().then()  ... inside then() you will get return data i think...

Answer (score 1):

Since the Yelp.search function is async, it will always return a promise. That's the reason you observe a promise when you log the immediate result after calling it. Instead, you should await the promise like:

```
Yelp.search('pasta', 'london', 'best_match').then(results => {
    console.log(results)
})
```

So to answer your question, you would call the then() method of the Promise to wait for its results to resolve. The then method takes two arguments. The first is a function that you provide to handle the results of the promise. The second is a function that you provide to handle any errors returned by the promise. For example:

```
Yelp.search('pasta', 'london', 'best_match').then(results => {
    // handle the results
    console.log(results)
}, err => {
    // handle the error
    console.error(err)
})
```

You may also catch exceptions thrown by the promise by invoking catch(), like so:

```
Yelp.search('pasta', 'london', 'best_match')
    .then(results => console.log(results), err => console.error(err))
    .catch(ex => console.error(ex))
```